# İf they have same tangent line ,why their slopes are different .I don't understand.

Tags: calculus, functional-calculus

> Lep $P=(x_1,y_1)$ be a point taken on the curve $y=x^3$.
>
> The tangent line of this curve at $P$ meets the curve again at another point $Q=(x_2,y_2)$.
>
> Prove that the slope of the curve at $Q$ is four times the slope at $P$.

How can I prove it ?

Comment: Please type the text instead of an image with two lines of text !

Comment: Take the first derivative, which gives you the slope of tangent lines at point $x$. Then for any $(x,y) $, find the intersection of the tangent line defined through $(x,y)$ with $y = x^3$ which will give you a second coordinate pair $(x',y') $. Finally, take the derivative at this new $x'$.

Comment: This question's image not lines image.I cannot write the question with my keyboard

Comment: The tangent line is only at one point P and cross the curve at another point Q.The goal is to compute the slope at this other point. The line is not tangent in Q it just has an intersection.

Comment: Please don't post images instead of text in your future questions. It's very uncomfortable, and you cannot do queries on images!

Answer (score 2):

They don't have the same tangent line. You have a line $L$
which is tangent to the curve at $P$. It hits the curve in a second point, $Q$. But it isn't tangent to the curve at $Q$: the tangent at $Q$ is a **different** line $L'$ say.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have the same tangent line. The tangent line is tangent at $P$(by definition), but at $Q$ the graph of the curve and the tangent at $P$ cross themselves.

For example
[look here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28x%5E3,1%2B3*%28x-1%29%29), 
The point $P$ where it is tangent, whould be $(1,1)$ but in the other $Q$ it wouldn't.